How to change the width of NavigationViewItem in WPF UI Library by lepo.co?
i'm trying to figure out how to change the width of the navigationviewitem because the content, which is the text inside navigationviewitem gets cut off, so i'd like to make it longer so it doesn't get cut off.
private ObservableCollection<object> _menuItems = new()
{
    new NavigationViewItem()
    {
        Content = "Home123123123123123",
        Icon = new SymbolIcon { Symbol = SymbolRegular.Home24 },
        TargetPageType = typeof(Views.Pages.DashboardPage)
    }
};


<ui:NavigationView
    x:Name="RootNavigation"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Padding="42,0,42,0"
    BreadcrumbBar="{Binding ElementName=BreadcrumbBar}"
    FooterMenuItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.FooterMenuItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    FrameMargin="0"
    IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
    IsPaneToggleVisible="True"
    MenuItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.MenuItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    PaneDisplayMode="LeftFluent">
</ui:NavigationView>

